# Entity Framework Update Problem When applying current values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

This code is giving an error when trying to update the database

> Error:An object with a key that
>   matches the key of the supplied object
>   could not be found in the
>   ObjectStateManager. Verify that the
>   key values of the supplied object
>   match the key values of the object to
>   which changes must be applied.

```
 public void UpdateAccuralSettings(SystemTolerance updatedObject)

    {
        _source.SystemTolerances.ApplyCurrentValues(updatedObject);
        _source.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ApplyCurrentValues` works only if entity is first loaded from the database (if you don't use the same context you used for loading it before it is most probably not):

```
public void UpdateAccuralSettings(SystemTolerance updatedObject)
{
    _source.SystemTolerances.Single(x => x.Id == updatedObject.Id);
    _source.SystemTolerances.ApplyCurrentValues(updatedObject);
    _source.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want to just save your current data without reloading entity use:

```
public void UpdateAccuralSettings(SystemTolerance updatedObject)
{
    _source.SystemTolerances.Attach(updatedObject);
    _source.ObjectStateManager.ChangeEntityState(updatedObject, EntityState.Modified);
    _source.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

could be that you model.edmx is not up-to-date ? // database has changed ?

depending on you setup/environment i think just a .SaveChanges() on the right Entitie-Context ( from which updatedObject has been created ) would do the update in db.

so ev just _source.SaveChanges();

greetings